# How to Sort an Javascript Array with IndexString eg: a['String']

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i Have a JS array Like this

```
CDate['1997-02-11']={dc: 3, da: 1, dm: 4};
CDate['1998-03-18']={dc: 6, da: 1, dm: 1};
CDate['1999-02-1']={dc: 4, da: 1, dm: 0};
CDate['2001-02-11']={dc: 1, da: 1, dm: 4};
CDate['2000-02-11']={dc: 3, da: 1, dm: 4};
CDate['1985-03-18']={dc: 6, da: 1, dm: 1};
CDate['1999-02-1']={dc: 4, da: 1, dm: 0};
```

and im using this CDates for a function to split the data into 4 arrays for a graph

```
for(var Dt in cDate)
{    console.log(Dt);
     chDate.push(Dt);
     chDa.push(cDate[Dt].da);
     chDm.push(cDate[Dt].dm);
     chDc.push(cDate[Dt].dc);
};
```

and in console i can see Dates printed bt not as sorted. so my graph doesnt looked in chronological order. wen i searched there are lot functions to sort array on key or property value bt not to sort "KEY" or "INDEX"..

Is there any way for this ?

Comment: `CDate` is not an array, but an object. It cannot be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations:

- `CDate` is not an array, it's an object. Object properties are unsorted in JavaScript and you cannot have repeated keys in an object (as you have for key `1999-02-1`).
- You can get the object's keys using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- The keys can then be sorted using the [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method, **but** because of how your dates are formatted, the natural (lexical) sort order is not suitable (e.g. `2017-01-10` will end up before `2017-02-2`).
  In the code below I corrected the date format. If you're unable to correct the date formats, you will have to write your own sort logic.

```js
let CDate = {};
CDate['1997-02-11']={dc: 3, da: 1, dm: 4};
CDate['1998-03-18']={dc: 6, da: 1, dm: 1};
CDate['1999-02-01']={dc: 4, da: 1, dm: 0};
CDate['2001-02-11']={dc: 1, da: 1, dm: 4};
CDate['2000-02-11']={dc: 3, da: 1, dm: 4};
CDate['1985-03-18']={dc: 6, da: 1, dm: 1};

let chDate = [];
let chDa = [];
let chDm = [];
let chDc = [];

let keys = Object.keys(CDate).sort();

keys.forEach(key => {
  chDate.push(key);
  chDa.push(CDate[key].da);
  chDm.push(CDate[key].dm);
  chDc.push(CDate[key].dc);
});

console.log(chDate);
console.log(chDa);
console.log(chDm);
console.log(chDc);
```

Comment: worked like a charm .. eventhough i declared CDate =[] !!

Answer (score 1):

```
var CDate = [];
var chDate = [];
var chDa = [];
var chDm = [];
var chDc = [];

CDate['1997-02-11']={dc: 3, da: 1, dm: 4};
CDate['1998-03-18']={dc: 6, da: 1, dm: 1};
CDate['1999-02-1']={dc: 4, da: 1, dm: 0};
CDate['2001-02-11']={dc: 1, da: 1, dm: 4};
CDate['2000-02-11']={dc: 3, da: 1, dm: 4};
CDate['1985-03-18']={dc: 6, da: 1, dm: 1};
CDate['1999-02-1']={dc: 4, da: 1, dm: 0};

var sortedData = Object.keys(CDate).sort();

for (var index = 0; index < sortedData.length; index++) {
    var data = CDate[sortedData[index]];
    console.log(data);
    chDate.push(data);
    chDa.push(data.da);
    chDm.push(data.dm);
    chDc.push(data.dc);
}

console.log(chDate);
console.log(chDa);
console.log(chDm);
console.log(chDc);
```